# How to make repetitive operations (loop) over a set of columns in a dataset in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, data-management

I have to make a series of operations over a subset of columns. I have a set of columns which measures the same thing to different parties A, B, and C:

```
id var1_A var1_B var1_C var2_A var2_B var2_C var3_A var3_B var3_C
```

So, in the example, var1_A var1_B var1_C refer to the same measurement for different parties. And var1_A, var2_A, var3_A refer to different variables for the same party A.

I would like to accomplish 2 things:

I need to create multiple data frames and merge the id with another dataframe, each one refers to one specific party. I wrote the code for each data frame individually, as the example below. The issue is that in the example it is simple. What complicates my life is that I have multiple datasets like df, and each of them contain information for multiple parties, and I end up with 50 lines of repetitive code. Is that a way to simplify?

```
df_A <- df %>% select(id var1_A var2_A var3_A)
df_A <- merge(df_A, df_merge, by="id")
df_B <- df %>% select(id var1_B var2_B var3_B)
df_B <- merge(df_B, df_merge, by="id")
df_C <- df %>% select(id var1_C var2_C var3_C)
df_C <- merge(df_C, df_merge, by="id")
```

The second thing I would like to accomplish is to change the variable name for df. I would like to change the variable name for all the columns that measure the same thing, but maintaining the party which it refers to. For example, say var1 refers to height, var2 refers to weight, and var3 refers to gender:

```
id var1_A var1_B var1_C var2_A var2_B var2_C var3_A var3_B var3_C
```

I would like to get something like:

```
id height_A height_B height_C weight_A weight_B weight_C gender_A gender_B gender_C
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with few lines of code? Or do I have to rename each of them individually (using rename command, for example)?

Comment: Without the exact data, it's a bit hard to give exact advice. But I'd consider reshaping your data to a long format. You have `var1/2/3` for 3 groups - `A/B/C`, so this could be `pivot_longer()`-ed to a three-column format of `id/group/var1/var2/var3` or possibly even `id/group/var/value`. That would reduce the need for separate selections of variables for each party.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try your suggestion and see the results. I will respond here if it worked, and if it didn't work I will post the data so my question may be easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tidy way:

```
require(tidyverse)

#CREATE DATA
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 var1_A = runif(10),
                 var1_B = runif(10),
                 var1_C = runif(10),
                 var2_A = runif(10),
                 var2_B = runif(10),
                 var2_C = runif(10),
                 var3_A = runif(10),
                 var3_B = runif(10),
                 var3_C = runif(10))

df_merge<-data.frame(id = 1:10,
                     value=11:20)
#grabs current names
nam<-colnames(df)

#Create map of new names
new_names = c('var1'='height','var2'='weight','var3'='gender')

#replace the strings with new strings in map 
nam <- str_replace_all(nam, new_names)

#reassign column names to dataframe
colnames(df)<-nam

# loop through all letters in list assign to variable 
#pasted with "df" and the letter, selects columns ending with 
# letter, merges with df_ids and returns the new subset of data
#to the assigned variable name


for (letter in c('A', "B", "C")){

  assign(paste("df", letter, sep = '_'),
         df%>%select(id, ends_with(letter))%>%
           merge(df_merge, by='id'))
}
```

Comment: This is awesome!! thank you!! And to me, as I am still a novice in the arts of R, this code is very intuitive too. So I guess I use the same intuition in other situations. Well, thank you.

Comment: @VictorShin You are very welcome. And you are right, Tidyverse methods are intuitive and simple, much more so than the ways on can do things manually. And they are usually faster to execute too.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to @thelatemail's comment (answer) above, but with a couple of extra subsequent steps, i.e. rename the columns, pivot the data to 'long' format, split the df into groups ("df_A", "df_B", "df_C"), pivot the data back to wide, and save the dfs to your global environment:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 var1_A = runif(10),
                 var1_B = runif(10),
                 var1_C = runif(10),
                 var2_A = runif(10),
                 var2_B = runif(10),
                 var2_C = runif(10),
                 var3_A = runif(10),
                 var3_B = runif(10),
                 var3_C = runif(10))

list_of_dfs <- df %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("var1"), ~gsub("var1", "height", .x)) %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("var2"), ~gsub("var2", "weight", .x)) %>%
  rename_with(.cols = starts_with("var3"), ~gsub("var3", "gender", .x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    str_detect(name, "_A") ~ "df_A",
    str_detect(name, "_B") ~ "df_B",
    str_detect(name, "_C") ~ "df_C"
    )) %>%
  split(., .$group)

df_list <- map(list_of_dfs, 
               \(x) pivot_wider(x, names_from = name,
                                values_from = value) %>%
                 select(-group))

list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ls()
#> [1] "df"          "df_A"        "df_B"        "df_C"        "df_list"    
#> [6] "list_of_dfs"
df_A
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>       id height_A weight_A gender_A
#>    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1   0.417   0.693    0.320  
#>  2     2   0.387   0.879    0.00590
#>  3     3   0.882   0.805    0.861  
#>  4     4   0.611   0.246    0.336  
#>  5     5   0.795   0.185    0.680  
#>  6     6   0.274   0.00675  0.568  
#>  7     7   0.722   0.950    0.757  
#>  8     8   0.776   0.757    0.0457 
#>  9     9   0.613   0.352    0.853  
#> 10    10   0.0603  0.438    0.421
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can then merge/join the dfs as required. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the purr package for?

Comment: The purrr package is for the `map()` function. You could also use `lapply()` and get the same outcome if you're opposed to purrr for some reason

Comment: I.e. `df_list <- lapply(1:length(list_of_dfs), function(x) (pivot_wider(list_of_dfs[[x]], names_from = name, values_from = value)) %>% select(-group))` is, I believe, the same as `df_list <- map(list_of_dfs, \(x) pivot_wider(x, names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% select(-group))`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not against any package, lol. It was just new to me and I wanted to understand the code. Thank you so much for the second suggestion as well!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you solved your problem